# A simple git configuration that allows for a push from local to remote?

Tags: git

I have two machines: **remote** and **local**.  I want **remote** to be my main repository that I can push to from **local**.

I have a current `project` that lives on **remote** that I would like to store into git's repository.

#### Answer

Since the files were originally on **remote** and I also needed a bare repository that I could push to on **remote**, this was a little tricky.  The procedure is essentially a *bootstrap* until I have the bare directory up.

The sequence I used to set-up and test, as suggested by **Paolo Capriotti** in his short answer below:

1. on **remote**, create a bare repo on `/home/me/depot/project`
2. on **remote**, also create a working .git repo
3. on **local**, clone from the working repo on **remote**
4. on **local**, edit .git/config so that [remote "origin"]'s url points to bare repo on **remote**
5. on **local**, edit some file, commit to working repo
6. on **local**, `git push origin master` to post to bare repo on **remote**
7. on **remote**, edit .git/config to point to the bare repo on **remote**
8. on **remote**, `git pull` to pull from bare repo

An even simpler sequence would involve ignoring the local directory completely.  First set up the working and bare repo on **remote** and then finally, on **local**, clone from the bare repo on **remote**.

#### Original Question

I have tried the following:

1. remote> git init && git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"
2. local> git clone ssh://remote/path_to_remote_git
3. `edit a file on local`
4. local> git commit -a
5. local> git pull
6. local> git push origin master

**fails**

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch:
>   refs/heads/master remote: error: By default, updating the current
>   branch in a non-bare repository remote: error: is denied, because it
>   will make the index and work tree inconsistent remote: error: with
>   what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match remote:
>   error: the work tree to HEAD.

So I start over: rm -rf .git directory on remote, rm -rf on local.

I try creating a bare directory on remote:

1. remote> export GIT_DIR=/home/me/depot/project.git
2. remote> git init && git add .

**fails**

> fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

**What series of steps do I have to go through so I can push from the local machine to the remote machine, starting with a `project` but no repositories?**

I prefer the depot in a `/home/me/depot` directory on remote if possible.

**Does that mean I need both a bare and a non-bare repository on remote?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a bare repository on remote with `git init --bare`, don't add any files yet. Create a repository on local, add your files, then push to remote.

Comment: So there is an empty bare on remote, and just a working repo on local?  Trying it out now...

Comment: ty - I think this works - I will update the OP to show what I did - had to modify the config file a bit since I needed to clone initially from remote (files didn't exist on local)